# React native: android OTP autofill

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

On my react native project, I'm trying to autofill SMS OTP on android. I tried using `autoComplete='sms-otp'` but wasn't able to achieve it.

My Code:

```
<TextInput
        placeholder="123"
        accessibilityLabel="Text input field"
        autoComplete="sms-otp"
      />
```

I am able to achieve it through [react-native-otp-verify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-verify) but it is a no-go as the expectation is to not have any special 'hash code' in the SMS, which this package needs.

Is there a better way to acheive it? I thought sms-otp on textinpit should do it but its not working. Is there any way to acheive otp autofill without having special hash code in SMS.